# Get value from Firebase Database to TextBlock

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, uwp

In Android I read the value from child A and write it in TextView:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("room").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String stringA = dataSnapshot.child("A").getValue(String.class);
            RoomATextView.setText(stringA);
```

I tried to achieve the same thing in UWP using [Firebase Database.net](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet) and its [C# samples](https://medium.com/step-up-labs/firebase-c-library-5c342989ad18), but nothing happened. How to retrieve this value from Firebase Database and write it in TextBlock?

```
var firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://my-root-address.com/room/");
var observable = firebase
    .Child("A")
    .AsObservable<Value>()
    .Subscribe(a => RoomATextView.Text=a.Key);

public class Value{
    public string value { get; set; }}
```

Comment: There are problems with that, i wrote my own communication library which recieves data by firebase REST api. I can't share this but it's simple.
One authorization OAuth request, at next normal request with access token, and finally one invalidate request.
EDIT. To textblock in code behind just assign value to text property.

Comment: Sadly I do not know how to start with .json to create a library based on firebase REST in UWP. Can I still read this value from FirebaseDatabase without auth? I mean, [I tried to assign "value" to text property](https://ibb.co/jcp8cm), but the app crashed. Can you help me, @AleksanderOrchowski ?